# C# get database id of selected item from auto complete text box

Tags: c#, sql, autocomplete, windowsformshost

[image]

I used this code to get first name from database and add it to textbox collection:

```
    String ConString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = |DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Lname,Fname,DDN FROM Staff", con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MyCollection.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }

        TNom.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
        con.Close();
    }
```

The autocomplete works, but I want to get the id of selected item and use it to fill datagrid view below

Answer (score 1):

This is *very* bare bones, is not practing good encapsulation, no "using" statement, needs error trapping...  that said, it should be a boilerplate for how you can take the value from the text box, get back a dataset for that and apply it to the grid:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from foo where bar = @BAR", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BAR", SqlDbType.VarChar));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = TNom.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```